# Rails New Article Error... Router error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When opening the url http://localhost:3000/articles/new , the html.erb file I created for that link does not appear. The only page that appears is the default rails home page. How do I fix this to access articles/new file?

[default rails page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRzBg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you haven't defined the resources for that route. In your route file;

```
resources :articles
```

Then in your **articles_controller.rb** you should have the new action

```
def new
end
```

Hope this helps.